# IOS NSPredicate not matching string

Tags: ios, objective-c, predicate

This is a simple question and I'm completely stumped...

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(centres, $centre, $centre.centrename == %@).@count > 0", @"EEE1"];
```

I am using above predicate to match centers which have the name EEE1. However, strangely enough the result returns: EEE1 and EEE2.

There are no whitespace's within the string and the data type within Core data is NSString.

If for example I change the centre name to HCC1 --- I get... GSZ4, HCC6, HCLH ,HCC2, HCC4, HCC1? WTF?

I must be missing something simple.

Centres is an NSSet.

*EDIT*

[image]
This is my code to filter the centres asset from the buildings object:

```
//-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
-(NSArray*)getBuildings:(BOOL)shouldFilter {
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Buildings"];

    if(shouldFilter) {
        NSSortDescriptor* descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"buildingname" ascending:YES];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[descriptor];
        //fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(centres, $centre, $centre.centrename == %@).@count > 0", @"HCC1"];
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY centres.centrename='HCGS'"];
    }

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* buildings = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Size of the centres: DUDE %lu: %i", (unsigned long)[[[[buildings objectAtIndex:0] centres] allObjects] count], shouldFilter);

    return buildings;
}
```

I need to fetch the buildings associated to the filtered centres because I am grouping my UITableView by the building.

Comment: 1. `+predicateWithFormat:` is a convenience method. You should use `+expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:`. 2. Why do you need a subquery at all in your case? 3. Set Core Data to verbose mode to see the generated SQL.

Comment: 4. This is no subquery.

Comment: I will try your suggestions, however, even if I don't use a subquery I get the same results, i.e. fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY centres.centrename == %@", @"EEE1"];

Comment: When I use the debugger I get: SELECT DISTINCT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZADDRESS, t0.ZBUILDINGNAME, t0.ZBUILDINGNUMBER, t0.ZDISTANCE, t0.ZLATITUDE, t0.ZLONGITUDE, t0.Z6BUILDINGS FROM ZBUILDINGS t0 JOIN ZCENTRE t1 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z3CENTRES WHERE  t1.ZCENTRENAME = ? ORDER BY t0.ZBUILDINGNAME

Comment: You are fetching from `centers`? Than simply use `centrename=%@`. BTW: `centrename` is a violation of the Cocoa naming rules.

Comment: I get the same results when using centrename = %@.

Comment: show a bit more of your structure and explain, what entities you want to have for which conditions (not as code but as mock or image)

Comment: Your code isn't filtering the `centres` at all; you're asking Core Data to give you the set of `buildings` where any of their `centres` match the provided `centrename`. Maybe you want to reverse the work: fetch the `centres` matching your `centrename` first, then follow the relationship the other direction to fetch the `buildings` (though it looks like you'll need to add that inverse relationship on `centres`).